# New to SharePoint (Office365): Best practice to organize my site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, library, wiki, architecture

We have migrated from Google Apps to Office 365 and now i need to organize a few things.

We have a few customers and each one will have a set of documents, a wiki and maybe a worklog (i'm using some kind of list for this).

So far i created a Document Library for each customer and am studying how to organize wiki and the worklog.

Create multiple libraries or lists within a site is a good choice?

While working on the SharePoint Designer 2013 for configuring everything noticed that there is an item called Subsites. Use a subsite for each customer would be a most recommended option and facilitate my work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely create subsite for each customer. That way you will have a dedicated area for all customer related content, whether it be documents, wiki, task list. You can also easily define permissions on a customer site level if needed later on.

So, a subsite for each customer, you can just use default Team site template for that. It will contain documents library by default. Then you can add wiki on the site, as well as tasks list. Also note the OneNote that is created on each site and accessible from the left navigation - it may come very handy in many scenarios when you wish to log meeting minutes of customer related meetings, etc.

On the main front page, you can put links to these sites, or even utilize SharePoint navigation for these.

I see no need to use SharePoint Designer for any of this, you can use browser to configure all this.

Comment: It all depends on your requirements, Subsites are great if you have Documents and Tasks and other types of information per Customer and you may want to give access to customers. If you only work with Documents a DocumentSet for each Customer in only one library may be enough and way easier to keep an overview. Try and taste everything SharePoint and only start building when you truly understand WHY you are using certain SharePoint components.